# generating a hyperlink to a plone document

Tags: hyperlink, content-management-system, plone

Newbie to Plone : how can i have a link to a Plone document from an external site ?

We have Plone to manage part of our content which consists of multiple terms and conditions pages that keep getting updated frequently.

We also have an external site that needs to display these Term and Condition pages.

How can i generate a hyperlink to that content in Plone ? Can i even do such a thing ?

My idea is to have a link on my site which when clicked will display the current version of the Term and Condition page in Plone as a plain HTML file.

Comment: Is your Plone site publicly accessible? Any piece of Plone content has a URL you can just include anywhere else, but anyone that can visit the site showing the link should also be able to access the Plone site.

Comment: In this respect Plone is *no different* from any other site, really.